# read files from an array in php

Tags: php, file

I'm trying to open a directory, read just files with a .txt format and then display the contents. I've coded it out, but it doesn't do anything, although it doesn't register any errors either. Any help?

```
$dir = 'information';
    If (is_dir($dir)) {
    $handle = opendir($dir);
    } else {
    echo "<p>There is a system error</p>";
}
$entry=array();
        while(false!==($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ( !strcmp($file, ".") || !strcmp($file, "..")) {
                }
                else if(substr($file, -4) == '.txt') {
                    $entry[] = $file;
                    }
            foreach ($entry as $txt_file) {
                    if(is_file($txt_file) && is_writable($txt_file))   {
                        $file_open = fopen($txt_file, 'r');
                        while (!feof($file_open)) {
                            echo"<p>$file_open</p>";    
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried to `var_dump` `$file` to see if an array with data is being returned?

Comment: *"although it doesn't register any errors either"* - So, how do we know if you are checking for them? http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: when i var dump $entry, it produces the below: array(0) { } array(0) { } array(1) { [0]=> string(15) "temperature.txt" } array(2) { [0]=> string(15) "temperature.txt" [1]=> string(14) "visibility.txt" } array(3) { [0]=> string(15) "temperature.txt" [1]=> string(14) "visibility.txt" [2]=> string(11) "weather.txt" }

Comment: Having the `foreach` loop inside the `while` loop seems to make rather little sense. And why are you checking files that you want to _read_ from for whether they are _writable_ …? FYI: `glob` can help you to “select” only the right files to begin with, and eliminates the need for the while loop altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Help is quite simple.

Instead

```
$dir = 'information';
If (is_dir($dir)) {
$handle = opendir($dir);
} else {
echo "<p>There is a system error</p>";
}
```

write (I am sorry for re-formatting of new lines)

```
$dir = 'information';
if(is_dir($dir))
{
    $handle = opendir($dir);
}
else
{
    echo "<p>There is a system error</p>";
}
```

because `if` **has to be written only smallcaps**, thus **not** `If`.

And the second part rewrite to (again, you may use your own formatting of new lines)

```
$entry=array();
$file = readdir($handle);
while($file !== false)
{
    if(!strcmp($file, ".") || !strcmp($file, ".."))
    {
    }
    elseif(substr($file, -4) == '.txt')
    {
        $entry[] = $file;
    }

    foreach ($entry as $txt_file)
    {
        if(is_file($txt_file) && is_writable($txt_file))
        {
            $file_open = fopen($txt_file, 'r');
            while(!feof($file_open))
            {
                echo"<p>$file_open</p>";    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

because PHP **has** `elseif`, **not** `else if` like JavaScript. Also I separated `$file = readdir($handle)` for possible source of error.

Code part

```
if(!strcmp($file, ".") || !strcmp($file, ".."))
{
}
elseif(substr($file, -4) == '.txt')
{
    $entry[] = $file;
}
```

should be shortened only to

```
if(substr($file, -4) == '.txt')
{
    $entry[] = $file;
}
```

because when if part is empty, then it is not neccessary.

That is all I can do for you at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating the directory with `readdir`, consider using [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) instead.  It allows you to specify a pattern and it returns all files that match it.

Secondly, your while loop has an error: you conditionally add the file name to the list of files, but then you always print every file name using a foreach loop.  On the first loop it will print the first file.  On the second loop it will print the first *and* second files, etc.  You should separate your while and foreach loops to fix that issue (i.e. unnest them).

Using glob, the modified code will look like:

```
$file_list = glob('/path/to/files/*.txt');

foreach ($file_list as $file_name) {
    if (is_file($file_name) && is_writable($file_name)) {
        // Do something with $file_name
    }
}
```